# How do you tell a new company you already have scheduled vacation?

Tags: new-job, vacation

I am interviewing for a new job and hoping to get an offer this week.  In about one month I am going to be out of town for 10 straight days due to scheduled vacations.  When should I tell the new company that I have to have this time off? Before I sign the offer letter or after?

Comment: Don't they ask if you have any planed leave during the interview process - seems rather unprofessional of HR not to do that

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be dishonest to not mention it before signing the offer letter. I certainly wouldn't mention it before an offer was given though. After they offer, just explain the situation, that you can't get out of the trip, and see what they say. It would be considered a normal part of pre-signing negotiations in my opinion.

I was in this situation before and was forced to make up the time beforehand on weekends. Other options are obviously unpaid vacation, delaying your start date, or an advance on your vacation with the understanding that they'd withhold pay if you suddenly quit for whatever reason.

Comment: And not forgetting that they would be within their rights to deny you the vacation completely, in which case you would have to bear the cancellation costs yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback anonymous downvoter!

Comment: @DJClayworth They can certainly deny you the vacation once you've accepted the offer, but not really before... at that point it's up to you to decide whether you want the job or the vacation. In my personal situation it was a honeymoon a month after I started, so that wasn't really something I could budge on which was why I made sure to discuss it when they proposed a start date.

Comment: +1, been in this situation and the appropriate time is after getting an offer but before accepting and signing it.